# Can't execute python program from any folder

Tags: python, path, python3

I have a python program in `~/bin` called `program.py`. If i'm in that folder, I can run the program from the terminal without problems, but if I'm in another folder I get:

```
python: can't open file 'program.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I have `~/bin` in the `PATH` variable, and I can run my bash scripts without problems from whatever folder.

What is happening?

DATA:

in this folder I have my python program:

```
$ pwd
/home/pol/bin/Python
$ head -1 program.py
#! /usr/bin/python3
$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
$ echo $PATH
/home/pol/bin:/usr/lib64/ccache:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin
$ program.py
bash: program.py: command not found
```

Comment: *How* are you trying to execute the program? it looks like you're doing something like `python program.py` - in that case, the shell only searches `PATH` for `python`

Comment: Yes, I'm doing `python program.py`. In that case, how can I execute the program from another folder? it is not possible? Your answer explains, as I understand, why I'm not having trouble with the bash scripts, because I only have to run `program.sh`...

Comment: You give it an appropriate shebang and make it executable, as shown in [Artem S. Tashkinov's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606297/65304) - then execute it using just `program.py`

Comment: I have done that with no success. I used the shebang Artem told me and only `#! python3` too. I changed the permissions with `chmod +x program.py` and `chmod 775 program.py` either, but I can't get the thing working. I suppose maybe these things are not the problem, as I can efectively run the program if I'm in its folder.

Comment: Your program is in `/home/pol/bin/Python` while PATH only contains `/home/pol/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a shebang? Your first line of the script should point to the actual interpreter, e.g.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Also, make sure the permissions are set correctly, e.g. you'll probably want something like 775.

Here's to show it works just fine:

```bsh
$ pwd
/tmp/test
$ ls
test.py
$ head -3 test.py 
#!/usr/bin/python3
# SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-2.0 OR GPL-3.0
#
$ export PATH=/tmp/test:$PATH
$ test.py
usb1              1d6b:0002 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (xhci-hcd 0000:04:00.1) hub
usb2              1d6b:0003 09 1IF  [USB 3.10, 10000 Mbps,   0mA] (xhci-hcd 0000:04:00.1) hub
usb3              1d6b:0002 09 1IF  [USB 2.00,   480 Mbps,   0mA] (xhci-hcd 0000:04:00.3) hub
...
skipped
```

i.e. everything works.

---

The actual answer after getting all the info: your program is in `/home/pol/bin/Python` while $PATH only contains `/home/pol/bin`. Move the program to `/home/pol/bin` or add `/home/pol/bin/Python` to $PATH.

Comment: Yes I have the shebang and the permission are ok, I have done `chmod +x program.py`. The programa executes correctly if I'm in its folder, so all this stuff must be ok I suppose.

Comment: See my comment: if everything is properly set up, it must work for you. If it doesn't **show your `echo $PATH`, show `head -1 yourscript.py`, show `which python`** (or python2/python3)

Comment: I have updated. Maybe I'm doing some dumb thing... sorry for that!

Comment: Thanks for the help Artem!